# In intervals, do you include the upper boundary when counting?

Tags: statistics

Say you have the intervals 0 - 3.5 and 3.5 - 7.5. Would the first interval include 0 up to and including 3.5 or would it include 0 up to but not including 3.5? If the first interval doesn't include 3.5, does that mean the second interval includes 3.5 up to but not including 7.5?

Comment: An interval should specify its state of inclusion or exclusion for each endpoint.  Typically there is notation such as $(,),[,]$ to indicate this.

Comment: The examples used in my textbook are frequency tables. It also doesn't state anything.